# WordPress if else logic

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a beginner with WordPress and I'm volunteering with an organization to help fix their website. I found a line of code that I need to fix. I want to change the code so that the link on the button will go to one of two forms, either the 10949 form (in the current code) or the 13808 form, or a page that has links to both. The values for "cat_pdf" will either be cat 13808, dog 10949, or blank. 
Here is the current code:

```
<li>
<?php  if(get_field('cat_pdf')) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $var = get_field('cat_pdf'); ?> " target="_blank" download>  ADOPTION APPLICATION </a>  
   <?php    } else { ?>  
      <a href="http://linktosite.org/machform/view.php?id=10949"> ADOPTION APPLICATION </a> 
            <?php } ?> 
</li>
```

Your help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the value for "cat_pdf" field - does this **only** contain the number (e.g., "10949"), or does it contain both the type **and** the number ("dog 10949")?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `cat_pdf` field does only contain the number (e.g., "10494"), it would simply work like this:

```
<li>
<?php  if ($type_id = get_field('cat_pdf')) { ?>
      <a href="http://linktosite.org/machform/view.php?id=<?= $type_id ?>"> ADOPTION APPLICATION </a> 
   <?php    } else { ?>

      <a href="http://linktosite.org/machform/view.php?id=10949"> ADOPTION APPLICATION </a> 
            <?php } ?> 
</li>
```

This outputs the `cat_pdf` value after `id=`. If this is more than just a number, please provide more information about the exact format of the `cat_pdf` field